# Reading XML / RSS in .Net using System.Data.DataSet?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2008

I really have not worked much with XML and I would appreciate some help.

I am trying to read an RSS feed from WeatherBug

I found some sample code here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/thibbard/archive/2006/01/13/65764.aspx

Where they are using System.Data.DataSet to read the XML feed.

(They are using VBasic I am using VC#)

Here is a sample of the XML I am trying to read:

http://api.wxbug.net/getLiveCompactWeatherRSS.aspx?ACode=A5333948364&zipcode=80918&unittype=0&OutputType=1

In the code example they get the wind speed as follows:

_wind = DS.Tables("wind-speed").Rows(0).Item("wind-speed_Text")

How do I know what to specify for each of the index values?  I think I understand how they determined to specify wind-speed but how did they determine how to specify wind-speed_Text?

I can see the values in my debugger using:

m_ds.Tables["wind-speed"].Rows[0].ItemArray

I can see 3 values. "MPH", "3" and 0.

MPH would be the units.  "3" would be the speed.  Not sure what 0 is.

And how would I access the value at aws:WebURL?

And I am only seeing 8 tables.But there are more values than that.  By poking around with the debugger, I found those URLs in the Weather table along with the values for wind-direction and gust-direction.

I thought I had the whole table thing nailed down but there seems to be no rhyme nor reason to it.

Can anyone put me on the right path?   Basically I just need to know how to figure out how to find stuff in the DataTables based on what I am seeing in the XML.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and easy:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://api.wxbug.net/getLiveCompactWeatherRSS.aspx?ACode=A5333948364&zipcode=80918&unittype=0&OutputType=1");
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.aws.com/aws";
            var webUrl = doc.Element(ns + "weather").Element(ns + "WebURL").Value;
            var wind = doc.Element(ns + "weather").Element(ns + "wind-speed").Value;
```

You can also use LINQ:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://api.wxbug.net/getLiveCompactWeatherRSS.aspx?ACode=A5333948364&zipcode=80918&unittype=0&OutputType=1");
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.aws.com/aws";
            var v = from d in doc.Elements(ns + "weather") select new { WebUrl = d.Element(ns + "WebURL").Value, WindSpeed = d.Element(ns + "wind-speed").Value};
            foreach (var c in v)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.WebUrl + "--" + c.WindSpeed);
            }
```

Comment: That does seem a lot easier.   Any idea why the original programmer went with System.Data.DataSet?

I have note coded in .Net a lot.  One thing I noticed it there are a ton of ways to do the same thing.  Maybe too many. :)  Also there seems to be a ton of methods and properties withing an object.  Maybe too many. :)

Comment: I understand on reason for using a dataset is that it can be bound to a control?  So why isn't the data being loaded in some logical manner?   It seems to be all over the place.

Comment: I would probably use plain C# based models instead of DataSets so that I can even add behaviors as well if needed.